# Counting number of control flow path

Tags: compilers

[image: this is the question]

1. I know the answer that it will be 1024(2^10). But iam not able to understand why, I have looked the answer but still don't find it compelling
2. My reason, it says ten if  are there in the language and since it follows the given grammar then the program having 10 'if' should be generated by it, which can be but in my opinion they should be non recursive that leads to like this
3. Statement, statement, statement.... up to 10.
4. But look closely they are linear  and the grammar is itself non recursive so an ' if' can't be nested here
5. So my answer is that the control flow path should be 20 only as with each statement we get 2 paths and here there are 10 state with each of them having 2 control flow path so answer is 10*2=20
6. I know that iam wrong here somewhere but I don't know where any help will be admirable

Comment: You need to think more about your argument (5).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Yeah for sure and iam working in how to use mathematics on stack exchange so, next time I will take care of that